# How do I print the current date without the dashes?

Tags: python, date

So I am trying to use the current date to generate an order number for my restaurant system but it prints it with dashes and I don't know how to remove those.
My current code for the date is below.

```
today = date.today
```

Whenever I print this the date prints out with dashes. Is there a way to remove those dashes from the code?

Comment: If you print that, it would it wold be something like `<built-in method today of type object at 0x...>`. Always make sure the code you post does what you describe!

Comment: If you want to get datetime with specific print format you can use `strftime` , example without dashes:
`today= datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")`

Comment: But remember strftime convert datetime to string which will help you show the date output as per your format, but after convert to strftime you cannot perform any further date operation,  either u need to convert it back or use before the strftime object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strftime` method of the `date` object.

```py
>>> today = date.today()
>>> today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'28/03/2022'
```

Here's the documentation on the [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) you can use.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the solution as correct so that other people can find it more easily!

Answer (score 0):

there is a better way,
try this code below.

```
import datetime
mylist = []
today = datetime.date.today()
mylist.append(today)
print(mylist)
```

Hope that worked!

Comment: I don't think that `[datetime.date(2022, 3, 28)]` is really the sort of output that they're looking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can access each individual year, month, or day by saying today.year, today.month, today.day